# how to write a value into a created Registry in Delphi

Tags: delphi

```
   myReg:=TRegistry.Create;
myReg.CreateKey('\sunandan123\');
//myReg.WriteString('Tile','1');
myReg.WriteString ('TileWallpaper','1') ;
```

This code gives an exception that i 'failed to set the value for 'TileWallpaper'. how to correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `CreateKey` doesn't open the key which is why the write fails.

The easiest solution is to replace the call to `CreateKey` with one to `OpenKey` passing `True` for the `CanCreate` parameter. This will create the key if it does not already exist, and then open it for you to use in subsequent method calls.

```
myReg.OpenKey('\sunandan123\', True);
myReg.WriteString ('TileWallpaper', '1');
```

And for the sake of completeness you should include error handling, try/finally around the lifetime of `myReg` etc.  I would also recommend that you explicitly set `RootKey` since at the moment you are relying on its default value of `HKCU`.

Answer (score 14):

I always do it like this.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var R: TRegistry;
begin
  R := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    if not R.OpenKey('Software\CompanyName\ProductName\SubKey', True) then
      RaiseLastOSError;
    R.WriteString('ValueName', '1');
    R.WriteString('Other Value Name', 'Some other value');
  finally R.Free;
  end;
end;
```